# How to add some action after document update in mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongoose

E.g. I have field `lastModified` and when object is modified this field should be updated with current date. How can I do this with mongoose.js?
Schema example:

```
var schema = new Schema({
    someFieldForUpdates: {
        type: String,
    },
    //when 1st field changed this one should be updated too
    lastModified: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now()
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be done with middlewares like post-save or pre-save maybe
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html

```
schema.post('save', function (doc) {
  console.log('%s has been saved', doc._id);
  // update another field 
})
```